# Recommendations on visualizing basic linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, education, big-list, visualization

I am teaching linear algebra this semester, and I would really like to recommend my students some cool youtube videos visualizing some simple stuff like the span of a set of vectors, linear dependence, subspaces (and their intersection and sum) and how does a basis give you a "coordinate system". And for future use, visualizing change of coordinates, linear transformations etc.

Strangely, I couldn't find such things myself which were *really* good. I would be very happy to get some recommendations from the community.

Comment: What would be most suitable depends a bit on what the students you are teaching are going to learn later in their education. What are they going to use their linear algebra for?

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for answering so late, but Essence of Linear Algebra by 3Blue1Brown is fantastic. I found it a year after my linear algebra course (which taught no geometry at all) and it made a lot of concepts feel far more concrete than when I first learned them. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab